# How To Solve Error: GameCharacter() takes no arguments

Tags: python, class, object

I Have Created A Game Character example which has name, x position and health. I based it on a tutorial I saw somewhere. I don't know what is wrong? I seem to have done everything exactly as I saw there. Please Help.

```
class GameCharacter:
 
  def _init_(self, name, x_pos, health):
    self.name = name
    self.x_pos = x_pos
    self.health = health

  def move(self, by_amount):
    self.x_pos += by_amount

  def take_damage(self, amount):
    self.health -= amount
    if self.health < 0:
     self.health = 0

  def check_is_dead(self):
    return self.health <= 0

  game_character = GameCharacter('Rick', 5, 100)
  
print(game_character.name)
```

Comment: `__init__()` is spelled with *two* underscores at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

`_init_` should be `__init__`

it's called a dunder init, aka double underscore

Answer (score 0):

Your game_character var is inside your class. Moving it outside should help

Answer (score 0):

i think this line with a Tab before it still is part of class codes:
game_character = GameCharacter('Rick', 5, 100)

so it would be:

```
class GameCharacter:

  def _init_(self, name, x_pos, health):
    self.name = name
    self.x_pos = x_pos
    self.health = health

  def move(self, by_amount):
    self.x_pos += by_amount

  def take_damage(self, amount):
    self.health -= amount
    if self.health < 0:
     self.health = 0

  def check_is_dead(self):
    return self.health <= 0
game_character = GameCharacter('Rick', 5, 100)

print(game_character.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

**game_character** should be outside of the class and `_init_` should be spelled `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

I follow the same lesson and got the same problem (i'm also an absolute beginner).

```
game_character = GameCharacter('Rick', 5, 100)
```

Should be

```
player_game_character = GameCharacter('Rick', 5, 100)
```

Or any new variable but not a variable with the same name than the class.

I hope it helps.

All best
Julien